# CSS Ignore sibling div

Tags: html, css, position, css-float

I am trying to achieve something that looks fairly simple, but I am not sure there is a way to get it done with css.

I have a list of tags that are displayed in a row. In the fiddle below, I fixed the size of the `tags-wrapper` to simulate the row wrapping.

Now what I would like to do is add the input straight after the last tag (on the same row ). I am not sure how that is possible, as this would mean the input would be inside of the `tags-wrapper` div ( which, please correct me if I am wrong, but I think is only achievable with an absolute positioned div).

Effectively what I would like to do is to ignore the `tags-wrapper` div and just place my input straight after the last `tag` div, but I can't change the html as I am developing with angular components and the input and the `tags-wrapper` are in different components.

```css
.tags-wrapper{
  width: 210px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.tag{
  padding: 2px 3px;
  margin: 1px 2px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

input{
  width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class='tags-wrapper'>
 <div class='tag'>Basketball</div>
 <div class='tag'>Football</div>
 <div class='tag'>Baseball</div>
</div>
<input placeholder='Search'>
```

Comment: Do you mean to say that you cannot add a wrapper around both the tags-wrapper and input all together which would allow you to position them as you want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve this with [`floating`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) the `.tag` elements as well as the input element.

> The float CSS property specifies that an element should be placed along the left or right side of its container, allowing text and inline elements to **wrap around it**. The element is **removed from the normal flow** of the web page, though still remaining a part of the flow

(— https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)

```css
.tags-wrapper {
  width: 210px;
}

.tag {
  padding: 2px 3px;
  margin: 1px 2px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
}

input {
  width: 60px;
  height: 18px;
  margin: 1px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class='tags-wrapper'>
  <div class='tag'>Basketball</div>
  <div class='tag'>Football</div>
  <div class='tag'>Baseball</div>
</div>
<input placeholder='Search'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your css:

```
display: inline;
```

```css
.tags-wrapper{
  width: 210px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: inline;
}

.tag{
  padding: 2px 3px;
  margin: 1px 2px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline;
}

input{
  width: 60px;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class='tags-wrapper'>
 <div class='tag'>Basketball</div>
 <div class='tag'>Football</div>
 <div class='tag'>Baseball</div>
</div>
<input placeholder='Search'>
```

Comment: The `input`needs to be on the last row, behind the last `.tag`.

Comment: OP mentioned this: Now what I would like to do is add the input straight after the last tag (on the same row ). If he wants them all on the same row, this is the easiest way. But since OP has an answer, and that had the inputs not on the same row, I assume it was just an unclear statement on the OPs part.